# XML-RPC Communication with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, protocols, xml-rpc, network-protocols

I'm working on a system for my workplace that can track offending users in a computer lab. I have a system in place to track users (what their login name is, and vnc terminals available). This system uses a Windows Service to gather information about users logged into the lab computers. It responds to a master program running at a front-desk machine with a one line response containing the data about user sessions, etc. However, I would like to have a web app (WordPress plugin) be able to query these lab machines through my service installed on them to: obtain screenshots, send message popups (because `net send` is blocked on the network), and maybe more features to come.

The protocol I'm using is this:

1. Front Desk sends out a UDP packet with a single word `rollcall`
2. Lab Machines respond using TCP-connect back with data about user sessions

   - Packet response: `<machine name>;ROLLCALL;<username>;<domain>`
   - Packet reponse(alt): `<machine name>;<username>;<domain>;<table number>`

However, I'm not sure if I should be querying like this from the web. I'd prefer to try something like XML-RPC communication, but I can't find any examples of how to accomplish this in a Windows Service Application (non-ASP.NET).

**Does anyone have any recommendations?** I'd prefer an XML-RPC protocol because I'd like to experiment and learn XML-RPC.

Comment: XML-RPC is pretty much obsolete. Why do you think you should learn it?

Comment: @John - It's still used in numerous applications (mostly web-based). I've seen some examples and it seems pretty neat.

Comment: how numerous is "numerous", compared to "SOAP", which is based on XML-RPC and which has replaced it. I wouldn't bother with XML-RPC.

Comment: You can use WCF to create a "web service" that runs on the each system. XML-RPC is like Remoting that was used for .net 2.0 Nowadays we use WCF since its more powerful. You can check microsoft's documentation about remoting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @kurtnelle - Thanks. Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WCF to create a "web service" that runs on the each system. XML-RPC is like Remoting that was used for .net 2.0 Nowadays we use WCF since its more powerful. You can check Microsoft's documentation about [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I updated your link (it was from .NET 1.1). The new one says "This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the [Windows Communication Foundation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=127777) (WCF)."